# Unable to detect USB camera

Tags: usb, video, webcam, camera, image-processing

I am trying to use 5 USB cameras on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS in python3.6 using opencv3.4.1 through a simple program. I am just using 'cv2.videoCapture()' and then after reading the result use 'cv2.imshow()'.
Individually all cameras work fine, but as I connect them all together the following happens:

Mostly all cameras are successfully detected in start and are listed in lsusb as well as `ls /dev/video*`, but as I try to use them through my code in python one of these 5 cameras disappear and error like

```
 VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: index 0 is not correct!
```

is printed.A nd after that either `ls /dev/video*` does not show that camera or the camera name e.g. video0 is automatically changed to e.g. video6. I know if we restart PC the device names are changed but in this case I am not rebooting.

Sometimes the cameras are enlisted in both `lsusb` as well as in ls `/dev/video*` but while using select timeout appears.

Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Can `guvcview` open multiple streams simultaneously without issue?